# Specifying Image Integer Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am attempting to make a certain image a background image for an application. I know the syntax (`android:src="*int*"`), at least I think that's it. But I don't know what kind of a source I could use. A directory pointing to a file? A URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add/save/move the image to your res> drawable folder and have :

```
android:src ="@drawable/image"
```

Comment: Okay. But there are multiple drawable folders... Which do I put it in? Then when I reference it in the "android:src" thing, should I put the name of the file?

Comment: Create a folder in res called "drawable" and put it in that . For example if you have an image called "picture.png"

Comment: android:src = " @drawable/picture"